# In romaji is it okosan or oko-san?

Tags: word-choice, words, rōmaji

I am reading the Japanese for Busy People book and I notice in the dictionary in the back some of the words ending in san use a hyphen:

```
okyaku-san
```

and some don't

```
okosan
```

Sometimes they use a hyphen after o-

```
o-kashi
```

and sometimes not

```
okyaku-san
```

Does anyone have any idea why they do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a "right way". There are many ways to use romaji and each with their own rules. In general, names like Takeda-san, Takahashi-san tend to use the hyphen while words like okasan, otosan, etc tend to not use them.

The hyphen after the o is probably used to indicate that the o is not part of the word itself but just a polite prefix. But to use it or not is also dependent on what kind of romaji rules you abide to.